# Dynamically set [max] value in Angular Mat Range picket

Tags: javascript, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Max value in Mat ragepicker is not reflecting dynamically.
I have replicated the same below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uc41kx-7a8m4h?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.html
The below is what I have tried
I wanted to limit the date selection to only 29 days.
So when the date is changed the max value will be updated by
`startChange($event)` function using `(dateChange)` event.

```
startChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    let maxDate;
    this.minDate = event.value;
    maxDate = moment(this.minDate).add(29, 'days').toDate();
    if (this.currentDate < maxDate) {
      this.currentDate =  moment().toDate() ;
    } else {
    this.currentDate = moment(this.minDate).add(29, 'days').toDate();
    }
  }
```

But with the above is not working,

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: If you select an other date (03/06) for example, you want the range picker will be enabled until  06/25. Is it right?

Comment: Scenario1: if we select 01/Jan/2022 as from the date picker should set the to date as 30/Jan/2022.
Scenario 2: Max value should not exceed current date eg: if we select 01/March/2022 as from, the date picket should set the to date 17/March/2022.